# Is there such an expression like cheat somebody into doing something or cheat somebody to do something?

Tags: verbs

Is there such an expression like cheat somebody into doing something or cheat somebody to do something?

If not, is there a good replacement?

Comment: Replace _cheat_ with _trick_.

Comment: Replace *trick* with *con*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for '***trick*** *somebody into doing something*'?

[***trick***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trick) : a crafty procedure or practice meant to deceive or defraud

As @FumbleFingers points out, ***con*** also works and in some contexts is preferable.

[***con***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/con)   : swindle

Whereas *trick* can be used in situations where the deceit is more innocent or harmless, *con* usually implies a bit more *malice aforethought*.